# Haproxy Centos 7

Tags: centos7, haproxy

I am a newbie in setting up Haproxy and Nginx server.
However, i successfully setup Haproxy and two Nginx servers (All 3 different instances  from AWS).

**Case 1:** Haproxy (32.85.75.125) , Nginx1  - Web Server(34.214.118.85 :80) , Nginx2 - ApI (34.224.115.89:8080)
Works

My question is can HAproxy, 2 Nginx instances be on a single server instance and 2Nginx instances work by port forwarding?

**Case 2:** Installing Haproxy, Nginx1,Nginx 2 on (32.85.75.125)

Is case 2 correct ?

Comment: You will need to ensure that haproxy, nginx1 and nginx2 all use different listening ports, i.e. not all on port 80; or add dummy IP addresses and bind to port 80 on those IP addresses.

Comment: @wurtel Thanks for replying. That means, like in case 1 , all are different ports and it works fine. Case 2 is all same port

Comment: I don't know if I misunderstood your last comment, but to be clear: in **Case 2** each service needs its own port: HAProxy will listen on the address/port combination your clients will contact (for example 32.85.75.125:443), and then each Nginx instance will have its own port (for example 8443 and 8444, respectively).

Comment: I am sorry. I meant in case 2, all same instance , different port